# Copy one file to all folders in a folder?

Tags: php, file-io, directory, copy

Is it possible / easy to copy a file from one place (say `index.php` in `/mypage/homes/`) to folders in another folder (for example, in `friends` there might be `pfox`, `sam`, `uni`) using PHP?
So the file `index.php` would be copied to `friends/pfox`, `friends/uni` and so on?

---

To be obvious, the file structure is as so:

```
update.php (The file you have to write) 
mypage 
|_homes
      |_index.php 
friends 
|_pfox <--Copy index.php to here! 
|_sam  <--And here! 
|_uni  <--And here!
```

Comment: What if `/friends/one/sub` directory exists? Need you to put it into every subfolder too?

Comment: and why need you to copy php files? Maybe some redirect to first one will be better for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be something like this

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./friends') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDir()) {
         copy('./mypage/homes/index.php', $fileInfo->getPathname() . '/index.php');
    }
}
```

You might add code to test if `copy` failed.

Edit: Use `getPathname` instead of `getPath` .

Comment: And, if need recursive: `new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);`

Comment: This seems to silently fail. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Oh, it copies to the 'friends' directory instead of the directories INSIDE 'friends'!

Comment: @vp_arth Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in (redacted) on line 2

Comment: Updated code worked perfectly. Accepting as answer, thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php maybe?

The sintax is very simple

```
copy($file_path, $destination_path);
```